# Model Input: list of Numpy arrays passing to model is not size the model expected. Expected to see 1 array(s), but instead got list of 142 arrays

Tags: python, arrays

when i am trying to  predict using a piece of my dataset, i am getting following error:

```
Loading data...
test
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bgru.py", line 226, in <module>
    testrealdata(realtestdataSetPath, weightPath, batchSize, maxLen, vectorDim, layers, dropout)
  File "bgru.py", line 208, in testrealdata
    labels = model.predict(x = realdata[0],batch_size = 1)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1149, in predict
    x, _, _ = self._standardize_user_data(x)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 751, in _standardize_user_data
    exception_prefix='input')
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training_utils.py", line 102, in standardize_input_data
    str(len(data)) + ' arrays: ' + str(data)[:200] + '...')
ValueError: Error when checking model input: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 1 array(s), but instead got the following list of 142 arrays: [array([[array([ 0.55752313,  1.1673812 ,  0.34844342, -0.66672075,  0.7234713 ,
        0.36974093, -0.6329535 ,  0.06575115, -0.16997641, -0.00351257,
       -0.7482288 ,  1.3115643 ,  0.69816464, -...
```

I am new to this type of error and this area, how come i can overcome this error, where to do the changes??? Following is the piece of code that i was running :

```
print("Loading data...")
    for filename in os.listdir(realtestdataSetPath):
        print(filename)
        f = open(realtestpath+filename, "rb")
        realdata = pickle.load(f,encoding="latin1")
        f.close()

        labels = model.predict(x = realdata[0],batch_size = 1)
        for i in range(len(labels)):
            if labels[i][0] >= 0.5:
                print(realdata[1][i])
```

Comment: Looks like you are passing a array of array, see if you can pass as a single array,

Comment: @vinsentparamanantham  when i change my 'labels = model.predict(x = realdata[0],batch_size = 1)' to  'labels = model.predict(realdata[:1])' , I got this ValueError: Error when checking input: expected masking_1_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (142, 500)...     Do you know why this occurs??

Comment: Are you dealing with RGB or gray scale images? Also can you give some more details in your question about the dataset. x and y variables details

Comment: @vinsentparamanantham no i am not dealing with RGB or gray scale images.., initially my dataset is the C or C++ programs that are vulnerable or not, now its in the form of .pkl, the variable realdata reads the data(.pkl) for predicting..

Comment: We need to pass to the predict function as we have train the model, when we have a different size in predict function or different size of input that's when we end in  such error.

Comment: @vinsentparamanantham okay!!is their any solution for it??